# Convert Pandas DataFrame into a specific JSON format

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have this sample pandas dataframe:

```
data = {'type':  ['student', 'student', 'student','student','student','student'],
        'student_id':  ['12345', '12345', '12345','12345','21354','21354'],
        'student_name': ['Jane', 'Jane','Jane','Jane','Joe','Joe'],
        'deadline': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-01','2022-02-01','2022-02-01','2021-01-01','2021-01-01'],
        'subject_code': ['110', '112','110','116','110','116'],
        'subject_description': ['Math', 'Science','Math','PE','Math','PE'],
        'subject_grade': ['90.1', '92.2','88.6','90.1','90.2','89.4']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

**Question: Is it possible to transform this dataframe into a specific JSON Structure like below?**
[image]

I tried using groupby dataframe but I still can't make a structure like above. Is this achievable? Or do I need to restructure my table?

Answer (score 1):

Nested dictionaries from a dataframe can be tricky. This should work, but it's not quite as simple/clean as I'd like.

```
# Change columns to MultiIndex (splitting on '_')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuple(x.split('_')) for x in df.columns)

# Get initial dictionary from columns with only one level
data_dict = df[[col for col in df.columns if pd.isna(col[1])]].droplevel(-1, axis=1).to_dict(orient='index')

# Prepare a slice of the dataframe with the remaining 2-level columns
double_level = df[[col for col in df.columns if pd.notna(col[1])]]

# loop through the "double levels" and update starting dictionary
for top_level in list(set(x[0] for x in double_level.columns)):
    temp = {k: {top_level: v} for k,v in double_level.xs(top_level, axis=1).to_dict(orient='index').items()}
    for key in data_dict:
        data_dict[key] = {**data_dict[key], **temp[key]}

# create final list of records
records = list(data_dict.values())
```

Here's the output.

```
print(json.dumps(records, indent=4))

[
    {
        "type": "student",
        "deadline": "2021-01-01",
        "student": {
            "id": "12345",
            "name": "Jane"
        },
        "subject": {
            "code": "110",
            "description": "Math",
            "grade": "90.1"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "student",
        "deadline": "2021-01-01",
        "student": {
            "id": "12345",
            "name": "Jane"
        },
        "subject": {
            "code": "112",
            "description": "Science",
            "grade": "92.2"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "student",
        "deadline": "2022-02-01",
        "student": {
            "id": "12345",
            "name": "Jane"
        },
        "subject": {
            "code": "110",
            "description": "Math",
            "grade": "88.6"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "student",
        "deadline": "2022-02-01",
        "student": {
            "id": "12345",
            "name": "Jane"
        },
        "subject": {
            "code": "116",
            "description": "PE",
            "grade": "90.1"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "student",
        "deadline": "2021-01-01",
        "student": {
            "id": "21354",
            "name": "Joe"
        },
        "subject": {
            "code": "110",
            "description": "Math",
            "grade": "90.2"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "student",
        "deadline": "2021-01-01",
        "student": {
            "id": "21354",
            "name": "Joe"
        },
        "subject": {
            "code": "116",
            "description": "PE",
            "grade": "89.4"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `js = df.to_json(orient = 'records')` which is the closest possible

Please find the JSON structure using the above line
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3JjS.png

Probably you can try restructuring the JSON according to your needs